# System.Net.WebException exception - "The request was aborted. Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"

Tags: c#, ssl, readxml

I saw a lot of answers but it didn't work!!!!!
Here is my code:

```
  List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> lstItemsIndexC = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);

    xmlDoc.Load("https://apps.myexponet.com/apps/aspnet/budget/js/indices_heb.xml");
```

I get the following exception :

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted:
>   Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 31:
>   ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new
>   System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
>   Line 32:         Line 33:
>   xmlDoc.Load("https://apps.myexponet.com/apps/aspnet/budget/js/indices_heb.xml");
>   Line 34:  Line 35:         XmlNodeList MList =
>   xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/indices/date");

Can someone please help me?
I saw a lot of answers, but it didn't really work!
Thanks!

Comment: where is this being used `lstItemsIndexC` do a google search on how to use XPATH also

Comment: Do you have the security certificate installed?

Comment: Your `AcceptAllCertifications()` implementation must return `true` for the connection to proceed, does it?  (If it does not you will see that exact error)

Comment: Edit the question and add the `AcceptAllCertifications` method.

Comment: what is AcceptAllCertifications method?

Comment: can you write it?

Comment: I just need AcceptAllCertifications method? you can write it?